# Indices of cross-referenced lists

Tags: python, numpy

I'm cross-referencing two lists to find which items coincide between the two lists.  The first list `orig` is 32 items in size, and I'm cross-referencing it with a much-larger list `sdss` which is 112,000 items in size. So far this is what I've got:

```
for i in range(0,len(orig),1):
    if orig[i] in sdss:
        print('\n %s' % (orig[i]))
```

This gives me the items that are the same between the two lists, however, how would I efficiently return the indices (or location) of cross-referenced items inside of the `sdss` list (the larger list)?

EDIT: I guess I should've been clearer. I am actually cross-referencing two arrays with ints, not strings.

Comment: Are those elements sorted and unique in the input lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the order is not of importance you can use set intersection to find the unique common elements and list comprehension to get the index and element as tuple

```
[(sdss.index(common_element),common_element) for common_element in set(orig) & set(sdss)]
```

Note that "index" raises ValueError if the value is not found in the list but in this case the value WILL exist in sdss.  So, no need to worry about nonexistent elements throwing errors.

You can also use [numpy.intersect1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html)

Comment: I guess I should've been clearer.  I am actually cross-referencing two arrays of ints (not strings).  Should the above solution still work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find()` which gives the index of an item in a list, but returns -1 on failure:

```
for item in orig:
    index = sdss.find(item)
    if index != -1:
        print("\n %d" % index)
```

I modified how you iterated because you don't need the index in `orig`; you need each item.  BTW, you could have used `range(len(orig))` because your start and step arguments are already the defaults.